# Reinstalling Mathematica home edition with new linux distro

Tags: linux, installation

I bought *Mathematica* home edition and installed it under Ubuntu.
During an Ubuntu upgrade the power went out and wrecked the process.
I installed Linux Mate Debian Edition and tried to reinstall *Mathematica*. It refused to license itself claiming that it had been installed on a 'different' computer. The MAC addresses are still the same.

Wolfram does't provide support with Home Edition (though I think this is a bug) and suggested that I ask on this forum. Has anyone else bumped into this?

Comment: Just for the record, I was in the same situation right now: Mathematica 9 home edition, after reinstalling Windows, same OS, same machine (but different partitions, maybe it's what causes trouble). I used the contact form found from the activation window when launching Mathematica and I got a quick answer: activation code reset, and I was able to activate again.

Answer (score 11):

Pat,

Mathematica Home Edition customers get Premier Support (the "how to plot" kind of help) for 30 days from the day of purchase, and Installation Support (to get your copy of the product running again) forever after. 
At all times, Wolfram's Customer Support will be glad to reset your activation key so you can reinstall and use your Mathematica Home Edition on a different machine; you can reach them by calling 1-217-398-0700 ext 2, Mon-Fri 8am-5pm US Central Time, or by sending email to info@wolfram.com.

Could you please send me details on how you had contacted Wolfram Research?
Following your post we investigated to find out whom you had talked to, but were not able to identify any fitting record neither in our US nor our European offices (of course, we also don't quite know who you are).

Please rest assured that Wolfram Support will always try to help you get your Mathematica copy running again.
Also, if any questions on Wolfram's support levels remain, please feel free to contact me.

Peter Fleck 
Manager, Wolfram Technology Group 
Wolfram Research, Inc. 
support@wolfram.com

Answer (score 6):

> Wolfram don't provide support with Home Edition and **suggested that I ask on this forum**.

I hope it is because we are so awesome and not because we don't have to be paid.

> It refused to license itself claiming that it had been installed on a 'different' computer.-- mac addresses are still the same.

The MAC address is not the crucial thing here, because a desktop license is always bound to the machine *and* the operating system and *Wolfram* uses several things to determine whether the environment you installed *Mathematica* has been altered. Therefore, a change of the Linux distribution invalidates your license.

I'm not sure whether I can help you, but usually when you bought a *Mathematica* license (and probably you have to register it) and you created a login at https://user.wolfram.com you should see your product when you navigate to *My Products and Services*:

> [image: user page]
>   <sub>(source: [wolfram.com](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/data/uploads/2011/12/myproductsandservices.png))</sub>

When you click on the product you bought (in the image above it would be the *Mathematica* link), you get the details to your license and nowadays you can manage your *Activation Keys* from there. In this page, you have the opportunity to *deactivate* an activation key which is currently in use

> [image]

After deactivation, you can reuse the activation key (which is displayed in the first column of this table, which is not visible for the obvious reason).

If the situation for a *Home License* is completely different, then you could have a look in the [*Mathematica* knowledge base](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/topic/mathematica/activation-mathematica) which has a separate section about activation and license problems. Unfortunately, most articles end with *please contact the Wolfram support*).

Comment: Where's your Donate button? :)

Comment: @cormullion Don't you think it is a bit brazen, that the support refers to bluntly to this site? I mean in the end it is a license question and we cannot really do something about it. Wolfram has to manage this.

Comment: I was going to ask the OP what was said exactly. I would see licensing issues as being part of the legal seller/purchaser contract. Whereas "how do I plot a sine curve?" is what I would consider "support". Like you, I hope that WRI didn't say really say that licensing issues are not their concern.

Comment: Thanks guys. Didn't help as the user portal does not show the activation code. however if I try to put it in it pops up and says "error.. already registered" Frankly my experience with Wolfram has been appalling. Hard to credit that these guys write code for a living!

Comment: I agree it is brazen. It was just a very unprofessional brush-off. I spent a lot of time trying other routes just 'cos it is a bit embarrassing to ask on here. Sorry all.

Comment: @patmacC Here is what you do. Write to the support, that you changed the operating system, that your activation key is no longer working and that they should reset it. It was how it worked for me for years with my *home use license*, because I buy a new pc very regulary.

Comment: @halirutan, when I clicked on the Deactivate button I got a message stating that the code would not be available anymore. So how to reuse it?

Comment: @Sigur Unfortunately, I'm not sure anymore whether the "Deactivate" button does what he is supposed to do. I thought, that I can *invalidate* the usage of an ActivationKey to reuse it when I reinstall a machine or buy a new one. In the beginning of this year, I tried it and the complete row vanished which left me a bit stunned. Before you deactivate something you cannot activate again later, please ask the support how this is supposed to be used.